# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable .....?

Tags: object, int

```
  if (a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0) or (a % 2 == 0 and b % 3 == 0):
          pav=0
          pas=1
          for i in range(a):
              for j in range(b):
                  if(matrix[i][j]==0 and i+1<=a and j+1<=b):
                      if(matrix[i][j+1]==0 and matrix[i+1][j]==0):
                          a[i][j]=a[i][j+1]=a[i+1][j]=pas
                          pas+=1
                          pav+=1
                  if matrix[i+1][j+2]==0:
                      if(matrix[i][j+2]==0 and matrix[i+1][j+1]==0):
                         matrix[i+1][j+2]=matrix[i][j+2]=matrix[i+1][j+1]=pas
                         pas+=1
                         pav+=1
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Loading/PycharmProjects/Test/test.py", line 14, in 
    example.check_numbers(matrix,a, b)

File "C:\Users\Loading\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\example.py", line 30, in check_numbers
    a[i][j]=a[i][j+1]=a[i+1][j]=pas

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this isn't a complete example because the initialization of `a` isn't shown. But it looks like you're taking the mod of `a` and later indexing into it as if it's a list. Please show your complete code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a[i][j]=a[i][j+1]=a[i+1][j]=pas` This line. You are treating `a` as an array, and yet you clearly have it defined as an integer outside of the code snippet as you are using modulus with it.

Whenever you get the error `object is not subscriptable` it means you are trying to treat an object as an array.

Comment: all i want is to get the value of all point in the matrix index that i obtained to be equal with pas ....some sugestions?

Comment: This would be helpful to put in the original question

Comment: My suggestion is to have a `matches` array, where each index is added to when it is found to be equal to `pas`. Once the for loop is complete, the matches array will contain all the matrix indexes that equal `pas`